# Can I make Excel add cells together if they fall between dates and match another criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I'm trying to count the number of widgets sold across a number of different shops on a street, within a certain time frame.

[image: Here is my data table]

[image: And here is the results table I'm trying to populate]

If I could get a VLOOKUP to work, it would look something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(Streetname,Streetcolumn,if(date>=startdate,if(date<=enddate)
```

But obviously that's just gibberish but hopefully someone might know the answer!

Comment: you want SUMIFS()

Comment: @EmilyHua FYI,  and also to not discourage the OP, `SUMIFS` has been available since **Excel 2007**

Comment: Of course it is! Thanks everyone, that's the ticket!

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld, thanks for your correction, I will delete the previous comment and copy the reference here. [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)